# Fields don't match but the test was still passed. [Mockito Test]

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have the following test set up. I don't understand how the test is passing successfully since the user is set to "Dummy."

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TodoServiceAbstractImplTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    TodoServiceAbstractImpl todoServiceAbstractImpl = new TodoServiceAbstractImpl();

    @Mock
    SomeRandomClass someRandomClass;

    @Mock
    TodoServiceAbstract todoServiceAbstract;

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveTodo_usingAMock(){

        todoServiceAbstractImpl.setUser("Dummy"); //Set the user to be "Dummy" already

        assertEquals(null,todoServiceAbstractImpl.getUser()); //Why is the user is still null?

    }
}
```

Here are the relevant classes. I created them to test Mockito as I am still learning testing in Spring Boot.

Definition of the SomeRandomClass:

```
public class SomeRandomClass{

    private String field;

     public SomeRandomClass(){
    }

    public SomeRandomClass(String field){
        setRandom(field);
    }

    public void setRandom(String field){
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getRandom(){
        return field;
    }

}
```

Definition of the Abstract class:

```
public abstract class TodoServiceAbstract {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRandomClass RandomUser;

    public TodoServiceAbstract(){
        //RandomUser = new SomeRandomClass();
    }


    public void setUser(String user){
        this.RandomUser.setRandom(user);
    }

    public String getUser(){
        return RandomUser.getRandom();
    } 


    public abstract List<String> retrieveTodos(String user);


}
```

Definition of the Abstract Implementation

```
public class TodoServiceAbstractImpl extends TodoServiceAbstract{


    public List<String> retrieveTodos(String user){
        if(user == getUser()){
            return Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2",
                "item 3");
        }

        return Arrays.asList("Random item");

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect something else than `null`? `SomeRandomClass` is mocked so it obviously doesn't actually set anything when calling `setUser`. And why should it? That's the point of a mock.

Comment: @Tom Your comment is the correct answer.  If you post it as an answer, I shall upvote it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Feel free to do that yourself, I don't answer such questions. Thank you :).

Comment: @Tom yeah you right. I shouldn't be expecting anything. I'm new to the testing world and was trying to figure why my code didn't work before understanding Mock. This post helped me a lot though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277039/how-do-mock-frameworks-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Tom already said in the comments, this test is testing your mocks, rather than your actual implementation. Since you mocked `SomeRandomClass`, your tests should verify if that method is being called. In this case you should test if `SomeRandomClass.setRandom()` is called when you call `setUser()` and likewise, you should test if `SomeRandomClass.getRandom()` is called when you call `getUser()`.

For example:

```
@Test
public void getUser_shouldUseGetRandom() {
    when(someRandomClass.getRandom()).thenReturn("data");
    assertEquals("data", todoServiceAbstractImpl.getUser());
}
```

To test `setUser()` you can do something like:

```
@Test
public void setUser_shouldUseSetRandom() {
  todoServiceAbstractImpl.setUser("data");
  verify(someRandomClass).setRandom("data");
}
```

By mocking/stubbing you can write proper unit tests for `TodoServiceAbstractImpl` without having to take the behaviour of `SomeRandomClass`.

Answer (score 3):

[Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) answered in the comments:

> Why do you expect something else than `null`? `SomeRandomClass` is mocked so it obviously doesn't actually set anything when calling `setUser`. And why should it? That's the point of a mock.

Remember that mocked implementations are not real, and in particular unstubbed calls will return dummy values such as `null`, `0`, or an empty string.